# cursor is not a function - mongoose error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm using mongoose last version (6.3.1) and keep getting the error:
**TypeError: this.myModel.find(...).cursor is not a function**

when running the following function which supposed to bring from db all expired dates.
(I'm using node 16, NestJS)

```
 async getOldDates(old: Date) {
    return this.myModel.find({
        expires: { $lt: old },
      }).cursor();   }
```

I tried to uninstall and install again mongoose and still doesn't work.
I checked docs and syntax seems right.

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing
`.cursor()`

find() should just return an iterable object.